# How to set var value from a datasource file?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, var, imacros

hi everyone :) english isn't my first language so **please excuse any mistakes**, i want to run imacros with the **var** value from a datasource file instead of a hardcoded value, I don't have a great knowledge in programming, but i tried some of the methods but it always ends up with fails

**Here is the code that i'm trying:**

```
    var load;
    load = 'CODE: ';
    load += 'SET !DATASOURCE eacc.csv' + '\n';
    load += 'SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3' + '\n';
    iimSet('i', I);
    load += 'SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}' + '\n';
    load += 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}' + '\n';
    load += 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL2}}' + '\n';
    load += 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL3}}' + '\n';
    iimPlay(load)
    var COLUMN1 = iimGetLastExtract(1);
    var COLUMN2 = iimGetLastExtract(2);
    var COLUMN3 = iimGetLastExtract(3);

var a1 = {{COLUMN3}}
        for(var J = 1; J <= a1; J++)
        {
           xxxxxxxxxx
        }
```

i'm trying to put the column3 value to the LOOP

**Here is my datasource:**

```
XXX,YYY,10
XXX,YYY,20
XXX,YYY,05
XXX,YYY,13
```

so anyone know how to solve this and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can work with. With a little modifications on your side you will get what you want.

```
var load;
load = 'CODE: ';
load += 'SET !DATASOURCE eacc.csv' + '\n';
load += 'SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3' + '\n';

load += 'SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}' + '\n';
load += 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}' + '\n';
load += 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL2}}' + '\n';
load += 'ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL3}}' + '\n';

I = 1;
while (true) {
    iimSet('i', I);
    iimPlay(load)

    var COLUMN1 = iimGetLastExtract(1);
    var COLUMN2 = iimGetLastExtract(2);
    var COLUMN3 = iimGetLastExtract(3);

    if (COLUMN3 == null) {
        break;
    }

    var a1 = COLUMN3;
    for (var J = 1; J <= a1; J++) {
        ////xxxxxxxxxx
        alert(a1);
    }

    //alert(COLUMN3)
    I++;
}
```

Comment: thanks mate <3 you made my day it's working perfectly :) and thanks for sharing :)